# MATLAB: Working with RaspberryPi's cameraboard and simulink for real-time acquisition

Tags: linux, matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink, v4l2

In the past versions of MATLAB you could use USB-camera block to acquire by raspberryPi but there was some lag, so acquisition was not real-time.
With new Matlab version you can use matlab classes to control raspberry cameraboard:

http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/raspi/examples/working-with-raspberry-pi-camera-board.html

but you must set the duration of acquisition and it takes snapshot, etc...

I have followed this guide to use V4L2 camera block (usb-camera block) with cameraboard insted USB-camera:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=67424

by remote execution of Linux command in matlab (like [here](http://makerzone.mathworks.com/resources/remote-execution-of-linux-commands/)):

```
[status, message] = h.execute(['sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2'])
```

but acquisition is not real-time (there is again lag that I told above) like USB-cameras.

Using the Linux cameraboard command, instead, with:

```
[status, message] = h.execute(['raspivid -o vid.h264 -t 20000'])
```

where 20000 is duration of acquisition in msec, it performs a real-time acquisition, so I was thinking to use that in a MATLAB Function block but I guess that class is not supported for code generation because it does not appear in [this list](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html) and furthermore I must specify duration.

Is there someway to use that in a simulink block (working continuously) for real-time execution in this new matlab version?